# Do I get the bounty, if I answer my own question?

Tags: support, faq, bounties

I just wanted to know if the bounty goes away to other users. If my answer is best voted, to whom the bounty will go?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The bounty is automatically offered to the answer that:

- It is given after the bounty was started
- It has a score of at least +2
- It is not given from the user who offered the bounty

If two or more eligible answers have the same score, the oldest answer is awarded the bounty.
If no answers meet these criteria, the bounty ends without it being awarded to any answer, and is not refunded to the bounty starter.

You cannot manually assign the bounty to your own answer; the award button will not be visible for your own answers.

#### References

- [How does the bounty system work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/16065/140449)
- [I just awarded myself a bounty](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/54998/140449)

Comment: what if my own answer gets +2 and the other doesn't?

Comment: It makes no difference...you can't award a bounty to yourself no matter what happens

Comment: Where does the bounty go?

Comment: i was asking because i have a similar thing going on [here](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/29534/how-to-place-custom-menu-in-user-profile).

Comment: It goes to the big pile of unused bounty points in the sky :) Seriously though, once you offer a bounty you've lost those points. There are some occasions when moderators will close/delete a question when a bounty has been offered in error, and refund the points...but as I understand it those occasions are quite rare

Comment: Instead of it, should I award it to a competing answer just as an encouragement. The answer did not solve my purpose, though.

Comment: If an answer didn't help you then awarding a bounty on it might give the wrong impression to future users, who would assume it was helpful in solving your problem. If it *was* helpful at then I'd award the bounty, if not, I'd just let it go :)

Comment: oh, now I got it. Thank you so much. I'll follow your instructions. Cheers :)